# Better solution for implementing async polling method?

Tags: c#, asynchronous, async-await

I already read [Stephen Toub's article](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/pfxteam/archive/2012/03/24/10287244.aspx) and [Stephen Cleary's post](http://blog.stephencleary.com/2012/02/async-and-await.html), but am still not clear on how to best implement an async method, which is polling a mail server.

From what I understand from those articles I like to optimise for offloading (not blocking UI thread) and for scalability (use least amount of resources). Now I ended up assuming that the usage of `Task.Delay` is the best way. However, I'm not sure on this. Is `TaskCompletionSource` in combination with a timer the better solution? Are there other solutions?

Here is what I have so far:

```
    private async Task<int> WaitForMessages()
    {
        int messageCount = popClient.GetMessageCount();

        while (messageCount == 0)
        {
            await Task.Delay(1000);
            messageCount = popClient.GetMessageCount();
        }

        return messageCount;
    }
```

PS: I know, cancellation and timeout is still missing.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`Task.Delay` is itself basically a `TaskCompletionSource` with a `Timer`. There's no point in recreating it yourself.

Using `Task.Delay` is great for polling with an asynchronous wait.

However, an async API where the **other side notifies you** is even better since you don't need to poll to begin-with. If you have control over `popClient` you might want to consider changing the API altogether.

Comment: Being notified by the other side wouldn't be very likely with POP unless the client was doing pretty much what this does any way (IMAP would be a different story). In between, being able to do `int messageCount = await popClient.GetMessageCountAsync();` would also be a boon, but I'm guessin the querent knows it would be great but simply doesn't have it available from the library.